# Swift FIRMessaging send push notification request on signup

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I was wondering how I could prompt the user with the well known *'app' wants to send you push notifications* after the user has registered as a user on my app and not as the user opens my app as default (without even being a user).

How would I do this? I thought you would only configure push notification settings in the appDelegate.swift? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask for permission for push notification anywhere you want, where realistically if your app has a login page, then for sure after login you need to do it.

You will need first to place the code which asks for the permission in a function in `AppDelegate.swift`.

```
func registerUserNotification() {


        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: { (bool, error) in

                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

                if (error == nil) {
                    // its required for iOS 11 to avoid getting warning about "UI API called on a background thread"
                     DispatchQueue.main.async {

                     UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

                   }
                }

            })


        } else {
            if UIApplication.shared.responds(to: #selector(UIApplication.registerUserNotificationSettings(_:))) {

                let types:UIUserNotificationType = ([.alert, .badge, .sound])
                let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: types, categories: nil)
                UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

            }

        }
}
```

**Note**: Also don't forget to `import UserNotifications` to be able to use the latest SDK for iOS 10.

in any view controller you need to reference the app delegate and call that function:

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.registerUserNotification()
```

**Update 1**:

You will need to implement the delegate of UNUserNotificationCenter as the following, place the following code at the end of AppDelegate out of class scope (}), this is required for iOS 10 :

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {


    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        print("Userinfo \(notification.request.content.userInfo)")



    }


    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        print("Userinfo \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")



    }



}
```

Comment: I there! I checked out your code, and it seems to be a lot of deprecated/wrong code. Have you tried this yourself? Thank you very much for trying to help me though, I appreciate it!

Comment: @askaale what swift are you using ? This is swift 3 ! There is nothing deprecated!

Comment: I am using Swift 3 as well. Strange.. Some of the errors are: "Use of undeclared type UNAuthorizationOptions", "Use of unresolved identifier "UNUserNotificationCenter", "abiguous reference to member application_" etc. Weird..

Comment: Oh, I see - sorry. I did it now, and it removed some errors! However, I am still getting an error for every 'application.' (ambiguous reference). I did also include 'UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate' in my code, to get rid of the delegate error I had previously. Do you know how to get rid of the application errors?

Comment: Thank you! I have imported UserNotifications, as well as included the delegate. However, the ambigious reference 'application.' has not disappeared. Do you know what could be the problem? I tried to replace it with just 'UIApplication' without any luck.

Comment: Strange, after the updated code I seem to get more errors, including: Redundant conformance of 'AppDelegate', and Objective-C method.... (on the two functions inside the extenstion).

Comment: i will upload for you an app delegate file, be sure that you haven't mistaken anything, are you sure your not using Swift 2.3 in Xcode 8 ? have you enabled use legacy swift language ?

Comment: Here is a pastebin of my code: http://pastebin.com/FN6JtBUF To be honest, I am not really sure. How do I check that?

Comment: okey here you go its my bad i supposed to test it before giving it to you: http://pastebin.com/1Bd5nurn , now it should work like a charm :)

Comment: @AaoIi I keep getting an error `UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication registerForRemoteNotifications]
PID: 21882, TID: 5629490, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.usernotifications.UNUserNotificationServiceConnection.call-out` and in the file it states `UIApplication.registerForRemoteNotifications() must be used from main thread only` - does this not work in iOS 11?

Comment: @pmanning i have updated my answer for iOS 11 support, you just need to call it inside the main thread `DispatchQueue.main.async {

                     UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

                   }` and it should be fine :)

Comment: Ahh i kept trying inside the view controller.  Thanks @AaoIi!  Any chance you know if you can run a completion on the `appDelegate.registerUserNotification()` inside the view controller?  ie i'm trying to perform a segue on completion

Answer (score 1):

You can go through all of the remote notification configuration outlined by Firebase but skip the steps that prompt the user with "app wants to send you push notifications". Then when your user has completed your registration process, request push notification authorization from iOS.

The following code shows the critical pieces that will display the system prompt to the user. They can be called at anytime. These are also the sames lines of code that need to be left out at app startup.

```
func turnOnNotifications() {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter
            .currentNotificationCenter()
            .requestAuthorizationWithOptions([.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]) { authorized, error in
        }
    } else {
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: .None)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error on the UNUserNotificationCenter, is this a mispelling? Thanks for trying to help me, though!

Comment: You will need to the following imports: Firebase, FirebaseMessaging, and UserNotifications

Comment: Yeah, I did - however, I managed to solve the problem with the full code above. Regardless, I would like to thank you for your contribution. I appreciate it.